# Is anyone still selling 'Gordita' by TDF?

Tags: fonts, font-licensing, identity

We would like to buy a license for the font Gordita by The Designers Foundry. They are working on a version 2.0, so they mailed us they don't sell it any longer. That's why I'm asking here. Perhaps anyone knows a reseller who can sell us a license for the font.

We fell in love with it and need it for an identity system. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated :)

Cheers,

Sim

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about purchasing software.

Comment: Ok. So I can't ask if anyone sells licenses for fonts here? Typography seems pretty on-topic in design.